# Delphi pegando valor do campo criado em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Crio em tempo de execução varios TRadioGroup:

```
Rdb1:= TRadioGroup.Create(Painel);
```

Mas com o mesmo nome "Rdb1". Minha dúvida é como eu pego o valor do campo que foi selecionado. Tentei fazer assim:

```
Rdb1.OnExit := Validacao;

procedure TFCad_AnaliseDeTendencias.Validacao(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  if Rdb1.ItemIndex = 1 then
  begin
    showmessage('Acertou');
  end;
```

Porém como eu tenho vários "Rdb1" ele pega o valor somente do ultimo RadioGroup criado.
Existe uma forma de eu pegar o valor do RadioGroup que foi "Clicado/Selecionado"?

Comment: Porque você não cria a quantidade de radiogroup dentro de um for, dando nomes para cada um deles depois que precisar pegar o valor de um determinado radiogroup use FIndComponent passando como parâmetro o nome que você deu. abraços!

Comment: " Porém como eu tenho vários "Rdb1" ... ". Não consegui entender. Você não pode ter vários componentes com o mesmo nome.consegue descrever melhor essa parte ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pelo que você explicou, você não tem vários componentes com o mesmo nome, e sim está utilizando a mesma variável para criar estes componentes. Uma forma de você não precisar se preocupar com isso, ao invés disso você pode apenas utilizar o `Sender` do procedimento da seguinte forma:

```
procedure TFCad_AnaliseDeTendencias.Validacao(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  if TRadioGroup(Sender).ItemIndex = 1 then
  begin
    showmessage('Acertou');
  end;
end;
```

Observação: É importante que ao criar o componente (`Create`) você determine um `name` único para ele:

```
Rdb1.name := 'Radio' + controle;
```

Sendo que `controle` é a variável que você vai precisar definir a lógica para ser gerada.

Comment: Digamos que eu queira jogar o valor "Acertou" para uma Edit, que foi criado da mesma forma que o TRadioGroup (Rdb1), como eu faria?
Tentei TEdit(Sender).Text := 'Acertou' mas não deu certo.

Comment: @TiagoCasanova embora sua pergunta seja relativamente simples, seria outra pergunta, e não relativo a que já foi respondida. Vou responder aqui no comentário mesmo, mas não é o procedimento correto. Se a resposta já lhe tirou a dúvida do que foi perguntado, marque como resposta correta.

Comment: `NomeEdit.Text := 'Acertou';` para atribuir. `Sender` é quem mandou a ação, nesse caso o `radio`

Comment: O problema que "NomeEdit" são todos com o mesmo nome. Se eu fizer NomeEdit.Text := 'Acertou', ele joga o valor no ultimo campo.

Comment: @TiagoCasanova é impossível que o nome do edit seja o mesmo. O nome é a propriedade `name`. O Delphi não permite 2 elementos com o mesmo `name` dentro de um .dfm.

Comment: Verdade me expressei errado. Se eu tenho uma String valor := 'Edit1', como eu faço Valor.name := 'Acertou' ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53746/discussion-between-tiago-casanova-and-sorack).